# Mybatis dynamic select query with prevention of 'no column exits' errors

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

What's the best approch to have a dynamic query like

```
select $dynamic_columns from table
```

But also prevent error like **column not found** and get result with available columns. considering `$dynamic_columns` is given by end users.

One approach would be to store the schema in java object and filter it. Again if schema is update in DB we will need to update the schema java object cache. is there any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with this as it is more vulnerable to *SQL injection*.

> Never let the user type something into a text field, instead build a
>   list for them to select from.

For building the list, I think the best approach is to use the JDBC method `DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(...)` to retrieve a list of columns for a table. I don't think there's a need to cache anything.